# Django Authorization - Return redirect within a function call

Tags: python, django, redirect, authorization

I'm adding some custom authorization to verify that logged in users have access to specific sections of my application.  It's not pretty, but it works:

```
view_permissions = {
    'admin_list': {
        'school':{'userrole':['S','A'], 'usertype':[]},
        'class':{'userrole':['S','A'], 'usertype':[]},
        ' ... '
    },
    'delete_object': { ... },
    'edit_object': { ... },
    }
}

def check_permissions(request, viewname, objecttype):
    if(request.user.userrole in view_permissions[viewname][objecttype]['userrole'] or 
       request.user.usertype in view_permissions[viewname][objecttype]['usertype']
    ):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def delete_object(request, objecttype, objectid):

    # Redirect to home page if not authorized
    if(not check_permissions(request, 'delete_object', objecttype)):
        return redirect('wakemeup:index')

    # Otherwise, continue processing
    myobject.delete()
    ...

    return admin_list(request, objecttype)
```

What I want to do is move the `redirect` to be inside the `check_permissions` function, something like this:

```
def check_permissions(request, viewname, objecttype):
    if( <check permissions are valid> ):
        pass # Authorized: Do nothing and continue with caller view logic
    else:
        return redirect('wakemeup:index') # Unauthorized: redirect to home

def delete_object(request, objecttype, objectid):

    # Redirect to home page if not authorized
    check_permissions(request, 'delete_object', objecttype))
```

The problem is that, the redirect inside the `check_permissions` function doesn't do anything.  It only redirects if I add a `return` to the calling logic:

```
def delete_object(request, objecttype, objectid):

    # Redirect to home page if not authorized
    return check_permissions(request, 'delete_object', objecttype))
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with the nested function call returning its output all the way to the original caller.  But is there a simple way I can get the redirect to work from within the `check_permissions` function?

### Edit

Updated function -- I have to access the `request` object via args[0], but I can access my other variables via `kwargs`.  I guess it's because in the forms, the request object is just passed under-the-covers and not as an argument.

```
def check_perm(view):
    viewname = view.__name__

    def view_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        objecttype = kwargs['objecttype']
        myuser = args[0].user

        if not (
            myuser.userrole in view_permissions[viewname][objecttype]['userrole'] or 
            myuser.usertype in view_permissions[viewname][objecttype]['usertype']
        ):
            # Invalid permission - redirect
            return redirect('wakemeup:index')

        # Valid permission - continue
        return view(*args, **kwargs)

    return view_wrapper

...

@check_perm
def delete_object(request, objecttype, objectid):
  ...
```

Comment: It would essentially mean rewriting your entire view code, but this sort of thing would be *a lot* easier if you switched to using class-based views and the [`PermissionRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin).

Comment: Yes, early on decided to bypass Django's ORM.  This has been a major headache, so I've learned my lesson for the next time around.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a function decorator is the perfect solution for this problem. The following allows you to check conditions (permissions), hijack the response with a redirect if necessary and if not, continue with the normal view response:

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def check_permissions(view):
    view_name = view.__name__

    def view_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # Check permissions here.
        if False or False or True:
            # Hijack response with a redirect if conditions not met.
            return redirect('wakemeup:index')

        # Conditions met, continue with normal response.
        return view(*args, **kwargs)

    return view_wrapper

@check_permissions
def delete_object(request, object_type, object_id):
    # Your normal view...
    return
```

Also, note the way it captures the view name. Much more dynamic in my opinion.

Comment: This is great!  I think this is what I was looking for.  However, how do I reference the variables that are passed into the view (i.e. request, objecttype...) within the view_wrapper?  I tried passing them via `kwargs` and `args`, but I can't reference them.

Comment: I got it to work.  See EDIT above.  Thank you!!  This is really awesome.

Comment: @ravioli You're welcome! And, based on your edit, I'm not sure you understand `*args` & `**kwargs`. If you don't understand them, I recommend reading this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3394898/5971137

Comment: I thought that using **kwargs would let me refer directly to the keyword arguments in the function (i.e. `objecttype`) instead of having to use `kwargs['objecttype']`. Is that not the case?  Should I modify my code somehow?

Comment: @ravioli Having `**kwargs` listed in the arguments of your function definition allows you capture any previously uncaptured keyword arguments in the form of a dictionary. For example, if the function's definition line were `def view(foo=None, **kwargs)` I could call it like `view(foo=1, hello=2, world=3)` and `kwargs`, in your function, would have a value of `{'hello': 2, 'world': 3}`.

Comment: Wonderful.  Thanks again for your help.